.net core 8 user client's JWT (access token) to authorize background job
I have an application with 3 services. (1) A frontend in .net Blazor, (2) .net Web API and worker server, (3) a separate .net Web API.
The frontend (1) is authenticated via OpenId (Keycloak) and the calls on (2) are authorized via JWT. However, I have background jobs running on (2) which call the API in (3) and must be authorized with JWT.
The problem is that I am not sure how to design this. (2) can authorize the user to run a job at all, that is fine. But how do I call from the worker/job (2) the API (3)? Do I need to create a separate openid client and authorize with a token in (2) to (3)?
Or is there a smarther solution to this?

Yea let the worker app use the client credentials flow to talk to your API and restrict the methods by a scope that only this client can call. This would mean make calls in the API specific for this worker and use the authorize tag with the relevant policies (scope)
